# ckeditor 5 and font size when pasting from Word documents

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I use CKEditor 5 and pasting from Word is working fine, however I noticed that font sizes are lost. I made sure to add all the font size, color, background color, family plugins and rebuild. However still the font sizes are lost during a copy and paste from Word. I even added a list of font sizes such as 11,12,14 etc and still no success.

So how does this page work?
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/pasting/paste-from-word.html

That maintains the font sizes during a copy and paste. I can't think of anything else to try.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late here, but I faced the same issue and was able to fix it by adding the "fontSize" section in the ClassicEditor.create section in my HTML.

```
 ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.editor'), {
            fontSize: {
                options: [],
                supportAllValues: true
            },
            initialData: ``,
            extraPlugins: [UsersAdapter, CommentsAdapter, TrackChangesAdapter],
            licenseKey: xbuyftcyetbcuweyrtcytq4',
            sidebar: {
                container: document.querySelector('.sidebar')
            },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

At which point are the font sizes lost? Inside ckeditor? when you save/export the ckeditor text?

ckeditor will convert your word text, and wrap text with different sizes in a span:

```
<span class="text-large">Large text</span>
```

This means on your website with the ckeditor you have to redeclare the font size somewhere in css:

```
<style>
.text-large {font-size:14pt;}
</style>
```

Always use pt units here when working with MS Word files. Trying to convert font sizes to pixels will not work and give you some unexpected results when you view the and a device with different screen resolution, for example very large or very small screens.

Comment: It it lost when you and cut and paste into the editor. The font size is the same throughout within the editor.